# How to get VSTS Metrics to get total number of build and releases?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, release, metrics, azure-pipelines

How do I get metrics in VSTS to get the total number of build/releases that have ever been done?

The VSTS "usage" area does not give me what im looking for.

PowerBI doesnt give me total releases either or builds (only gives metrics on XAMl builds).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it through VSTS REST API (need to statistic by yourself): [Builds](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds); [Release releases](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/releases)

Comment: I am interested in the portal displaying "how long the release took". How do I achieve this ?

Comment: Thanks, asked here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47645576/vsts-release-bubbling-up-release-quality-metrics