# VSTS Release : bubbling up release quality metrics

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, telemetry

We have a continuous deployment pipeline that is setup to deploy to a chain of environments.

In the portal, all I can see is the following :

[image]

How do I configure the portal such that it also shows :

- How long each release took, split by environment
- Historic graph which show release time taken over time, split by environment
- Failures split by environment over time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t configure VSTS to show these, there isn’t such feature available in VSTS. Also, there isn’t the official extension can show them.

Some widgets can add release information to dashboard, but don’t meet your requirement. ([Add release information to the dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/view-manage-releases#add-widget))

You can get such information through Release REST API: [Get a release](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/releases#get-a-release) (`timeToDeploy` value of each environment), so you can build an application (e.g. [VSTS extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/overview)) to statistics data and show them.